# Popup Menu not working as expected in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I have a recycler view and card view. The card layout has 3 dots which on clicked, shows popup menu. Everything is working fine, but there is a small problem. If I clicked the top card, popup menu is displayed at the bottom of recycler view. If I clicked the middle card the popup menu is displayed at the top-left of the activity and like so on. I want that, if card_1's popup menu is pressed, it should show at card_1 and similarly, popup menu should displayed at their respective cards. I don't know where the problem is. Please help!!!

Here is the Menu Layout menu_options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu1"
    android:title="Edit " />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu2"
    android:title="Delete " />
```

Here is the method by which menu shows up. It is in CardViewAdapter used for my Recycler View.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    ...

    threeDots = (TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.options);
    threeDots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, threeDots);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_options);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch (item.getItemId()){

                        case R.id.menu1: int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                                         onEdit(pos);
                                         break;

                        case R.id.menu2: Toast.makeText(context, "Swipe LEFT to delete the card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                              .show();
                                        break;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu  use your view (holder.view?) as anchor and gravity center or top | left

Comment: If `threeDots` is a field in the `Adapter` class, then it's unlikely that it's pointing to the right `View` for the clicked item. Change your anchor to the `View` passed into `onClick()`, since that will definitely be the currently-clicked `View`. That is, change to `new PopupMenu(context, view)`.

Comment: When I pass holder.threeDots in the new PopuoMenu(context, holder.threeDots), holder does'nt recognize threeDots and gives error. Can you show me how can I do this. - Mike M

Comment: That's not what I suggested. I said to use the `View` passed into `onClick()`; i.e., `new PopupMenu(context, view)`.

Comment: Like holder.cardView?. Like that

Comment: No, exactly as I typed – `new PopupMenu(context, view)`. Also, if you don't @username me, I don't get notified of your comments, since there's someone else here, too. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

```
...

holder.threeDots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.threeDots);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_options);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.menu1: int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                                     onEdit(pos);
                                     break;

                    case R.id.menu2: Toast.makeText(context, "Swipe LEFT to delete the card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                          .show();
                                    break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        popupMenu.show();
    }
});
```

}